# In Excel, why does PERCENTAGE format display change when adding a PERIOD “.” on the IF/VLOOKUP formula?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, concatenation

I'm using MS Excel 2016. I’m using this formula:

```
=IF(D8="","XX.XX%.",VLOOKUP(D8,P:Q,2,FALSE))
```

to display *12.34%*, which is exactly how it appears on the source cell. However, as soon as I concatenate a PERIOD – since it's the end of the sentence -- on the formula:

```
=IF(D8="","XX.XX%.",VLOOKUP(D8,P:Q,2,FALSE))&"."
```

I would get *0.1234.* on display.

Can anyone help me with how can I get **12.34%.** as the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are concatenating a number and a string, Excel automatically changes the number format to the General format. To define the format you want for your number, use the `TEXT` function.

```
TEXT(VLOOKUP(D8,P:Q,2,FALSE),"0.0%")&"."
```

Comment: he wants the format as `12.34%`, so maybe the right definition is `"0.00%"`.